# Angular 6 and DotNetNuke (DNN)

Tags: angular, angular6, dotnetnuke

I am trying to integrate an angular app into a DotNetNuke (DNN) SPA module.I know angular but I am a beginner with DNN, I have Chris Hammond's DDN templates installed and I know how to create and install a DNN module, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to integrate an angular app into a DNN module.

Comment: check this article it may help you https://www.dnn-connect.org/blogs/dnn-module-development-with-angular

Comment: Also, if you are using angularjs (v1), you can also check out my tutorials on DNNHero.  It is a subscription service, but you get video lessons and source code. https://www.dnnhero.com/course/advanced-dnn-module-development

Answer (score 0):

You can find a "scafolding angular project" here:
https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-Angular-6-7-CLI

And DNN module where to deploy your project:
SPA DNN9: https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-9.x-SPA-and-Angular-6-7

ASCX for all DNN: https://github.com/OPSI-srl/DNN-7.x-8.x-9.x-and-Angular-6-7

all works with dnn webapi and security.

I used these projects with my customers. 
Let me know

p.s. I'm not using Chris Hammond's DDN templates, it can be my next work. Let me know which version of template you are using.

thanks
Matteo

Comment: Matte B. How can I contact you about a small prototype using DNN 9.3.2 and Angular 9. Are your github projects easily upgreadable regarding DNN and Angular Versions?